# Laravel - Error X-CSRF Token

Tags: php, laravel, php7, php5, laravel-6

tengo un formulario donde recibo el email y password, los envio por post a una ruta api y me devuelve un 200 si el resultado ha sido correcto , un 400 incorrecto.

El error que me da por consola al hacer click en el botón de enviar que es cuando hace la llamada ajax por post es de "error x-csrf token", como podeis ver lo tengo tanto en el setup del ajax...en un botón hidden del form...pero no hace caso.

```
@extends('layouts.user-guest')

@section('content')

<p>
    LOGIN
</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @csrf
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Escribe tu email.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@endsection

@section('script')
    <script>

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $("#btnLogin").click(function(e) {

            $("#error-list").empty();
            $("#alert-ok").empty();

            var email = $("input[name=inputEmail]").val();
            var password = $("input[name=inputPassword]").val();

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ route('api.auth.login') }}",
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    email : email,
                    password : password
                },

                statusCode: {
                    200: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                        window.location = "{{ route('front.user.pages.home') }}"
                    },
                    400: function (response) {
                        alert('Error login/password');
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    401: function (response) {
                        alert('Error login/password');
                        alert(response);

                    },
                },
                error: function(data) {


                }
            });
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

Gracias,

Comment: Y si la declaras el method a tu form?

Comment: Por cierto si ya usas la directiva csrf entonces no es necesario que manualmente declares una etiqueta input hidden

Comment: Es como te dice BetaM, no es necesario que lo coloques doble.